# Smaller notification on the watchface

Tags: android, wear-os

How in the watchface set attribute (a flag?) to make notification appear in "small notification mode" - as below:

[image]

Instead of such:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible since release of new Android Wear Watchface API. To do that in our Activity that extends `CanvasWatchFaceService` on `onCreate()` we call:

```
 setWatchFaceStyle(new WatchFaceStyle.Builder(AnalogWatchFaceService.this)
                .setCardPeekMode(WatchFaceStyle.PEEK_MODE_SHORT)
                ...
                .build());
```

And **setCardPeekMode(WatchFaceStyle.PEEK_MODE_SHORT)** is a key there. It also can show a bigger peek card - `WatchFaceStyle.PEEK_MODE_VARIABLE`.